# Calling a tibco soap webservice using shell script

Tags: shell, soap, tibco

I am trying to calling a TIBCO soap based web service through shell script using curl. I am getting response as 200 ok but am not getting output in response.xml

Tibco webservice is deployed in three instances. I am trying to hit one of the instance and retrieve response but I am getting content-length as 0.

I tried using curl and wget to call webservice and retrieve response but am getting content-length as 0.

Below is the curl command:

```
    curl -v --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: "/ServiceImplV1.0/getInfo"/" --data @request2.xml http://sfapt-ap98t:4121/service/dataservice -o response.xml
    request2.xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.greatclips.com/ghf/tck/service/v1.0">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <v1:GetBaseLineRequest>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <UniqueRequestIdentifier>?</UniqueRequestIdentifier>
    </v1:GetBaseLineRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>


    Response Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 10.215.13.217...
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to dlfapt-ap98a (10.215.13.217) port 6121 (#0)
    > POST /service/addataservice HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
    > Host: dlfapt-ap98a:6121
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
    > SOAPAction: /ServiceImplV1.0/getBaseLineDetails/
    > Content-Length: 323
    >
    } [data not shown]
```

Response from server:

```
* upload completely sent off: 323 out of 323 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Content-Length: 0
    < Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 17:57:45 GMT
    * Server  is not blacklisted
    < Server:
    <
    100   323    0     0  100   323      0  19383 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 35888
    * Connection #0 to host dlfapt-ap98a left intact
```

Comment: so the `response.xml` doesn't get created or it is zero size? (Please update your Q with this imporant information (don't reply in comments, please!) ) . Good luck.

Comment: Maybe it's not in the directory you expect. Maybe try a hard path, i.e. `/tmp/response.xml` ? Good luck.

Comment: please reread my first comment. Good luck.